# How to prevent <input> from stretching table cell?

Tags: css, width, cell

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>one</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Draws a table which is just a bit wider than the word "one", and it's ok.

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>one</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='padding:0 0 0 0'>
      <input style='width:100%' value='1'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Draws a table which is 4 times wider than needed.

Please advise how to make the width of INPUT equal to 100% of non-stretched TD without assigning the width of TD itself?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `size` attribute to your input. For example:

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>one</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='padding:0 0 0 0'>
      <input size='1' value='1'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good one. Always great to know your HTML.

Comment: This answer works, but if I may add a little explanation... It seems as though the presence of the `size` attribute allows you to control the `<input>` with CSS. It doesn't matter what the value is (`size="1"` works fine for any target width) as long as it has some value.

Comment: @craigpatik You don't need to add a `size` attribute in order to apply a CSS `width` property. However, if you do, a CSS `width` will override whatever `size` value is provided. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rven16qf/2/) for reference.

Comment: @Quantastical You *do* need `size` if you want to use `width: 100%`, however this may only apply within table cells. See this demo which shows it both ways: http://codepen.io/patik/pen/JXrEGX

Comment: @craigpatik Ahh, thanks for clarifying the 100% width. Learn something new every day!